# I want to replace letters in sublimetext3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I want to replace letters in sublimetext3.
Code is like

```
aaa&bbb
```

so I want to replace

```
aaa<"bbb">
```

I put

```
([a-z]*)&([a-z]*)
```

to Find,and

```
$1<"$2">
```

to Replace and I put replace button,
but nothing was replaced.
What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: Try the replace string `\1<"\2">`. I tested it with `([a-z]+)&([a-z]+)`

Comment: Did you select a regular expression mode?